# Слишком большие числа для long long

Tags: c++, простые-числа, теория-чисел, факторизация

Есть функция `factorial(n)`, которая находит `n!`:

```cpp
long long factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

А также функция `factorization(n)`, которая находит разложение `n` на простые множители:

```cpp
vector<long long> factorization(long long n) {
   vector<long long> p;
   for (long long d = 2; d * d <= n; ++d) {
       while (n % d == 0){
           p.push_back(d);
           n /= d;
       }
   }
   if (n > 1)
       p.push_back(n);
   return p;
}
```

Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы найти `factorization(factorial(n))`. Проблема заключается в том, что `n` может быть достаточно большим (до 45 включительно), например 32. Тогда `32!` уже не будет вмещаться в `long long`.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Так вам же не нужно считать сам факториал,  если вы знаете его множители. Каждый множитель разложите на простые

Comment: Элементарно, Ват... Thwrani! Просто раскладывайте на простые множители числа от 2 до n. И собирайте все в одну кучу :)

Comment: Для этого есть библиотеки для работы с большими числами. Я бы не стал велосипед изобретать. Разве что для общего саморазвития. Но там нет ничего выдающегося. Просто массив чисел плюс учёт байтового порядка в системе. И ещё пара трюков с выводом.

Comment: @megorit Да зачем же из пушки по воробьям палить?...

Comment: Если у вам нужно найти факториал, результат которого не вмещается ни в long long, ни в unsigned long long, то попробуйте сделать свой тип, хранящий под коробкой какой-нибудь vector<unsigned char> или даже bitset. Байты в массиве будут байтами вашего числа, с ними и оперируете

Answer (score 3):

Я бы работал не через `vector`, а через `map`:

```
map<int,int> factorFactor(int n)
{
    map<int,int> M;
    for(int m = 2; m <= n; ++m)
    {
        int d = m;
        for(int i = 2; i*i <= d; ++i)
        {
            if (d%i) continue;
            while(d%i == 0)
            {
                M[i]++;
                d /= i;
            }
        }
        if (d > 1) M[d]++;
    }
    return M;
}
```

Так, по-моему, [удобнее](https://ideone.com/ysqJWI)...

Но, вообще говоря, можно еще проще и быстрее, если рассматривать количество вхождения простых множителей в факториал — например, для 100! число двоек равно

```
100/2 + 100/4 + 100/8 + 100/16 + 100/32 + 100/64 = 50+25+12+6+3+1 = 97
```

(деления целочисленные), то же для троек

```
100/3 + 100/9 + 100/27 + 100/81 = 33 + 11 + 3 + 1 = 48
```

(см. разложение по ссылке) и прочих простых чисел. Выбор за вами.

Answer (score 1):

Факторизация факториала отдельная задача потому что даже у больших факториалов все множители маленькие. Их можно найти быстро, если не вычислять сам факториал (медленно) и не разлагать его на простые (чрезвычайно медленно).

Почитайте как [разложить факториал на простые множители](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8). Формула не очень ясная, код проще:

```
// вычисляет степень простого основания p в n!
unsigned factorial_exponent(unsigned n, unsigned p) {
    // assert(is_prime(p));
    unsigned e = 0; // n / p + n / p^2 + n / p^3 + ...
    for (unsigned t = n / p; t > 0; t /= p) {
        e += t;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Чтобы воспользоваться этой функцией требуется найти все простые не более `n`. Напрашивается решето Эратосфена:

```
// все простые меньшие n
void get_primes(unsigned n, std::vector<unsigned> &primes) {
    primes.clear();
    std::vector<bool> sieve(n, true);
    unsigned i = 2;
    for (; i * i < n; ++i) {
        if (sieve[i]) {
            primes.push_back(i);
            for (unsigned j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for (; i < n; ++i) {
        if (sieve[i]) {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Всё готово для факторизации:

```
struct factor_t {
    unsigned p;
    unsigned e;
};

void factorial_factorization(unsigned n, std::vector<factor_t> &factors) {
    std::vector<unsigned> primes;
    get_primes(n + 1, primes);
    factors.clear();
    for (unsigned p : primes) {
        factors.push_back({p, factorial_exponent(n, p)});
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
int main() {
    unsigned n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<factor_t> factors;
    factorial_factorization(n, factors);
    for (const factor_t &f : factors) {
        std::cout << f.p << '^' << f.e << '\n';
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 factorial-factorization.cpp 
>
> $ echo 45 | ./a.out 
> 2^41
> 3^21
> 5^10
> 7^6
> 11^4
> 13^3
> 17^2
> 19^2
> 23^1
> 29^1
> 31^1
> 37^1
> 41^1
> 43^1
>
> $ time echo 1000000000 | ./a.out | wc -l
> 50847534
>
> real  0m16.632s
> user  0m16.776s
> sys   0m0.720s
> ```